# AOP + synchronized

Tags: java, concurrency, aop, guice

I'm not quite sure exactly how to go about this...so it may take me a few tries to get this question right.  I have a annotation for caching the results of a method.  My code is a private fork for now, but the part I'm working on starts from here:
https://code.google.com/p/cache4guice/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cache4guice/aop/CacheInterceptor.java#46

I have annotated a method that I want cached, that runs a VERY slow query, sometimes takes a few minutes to run.  The problem is, that my async web app keeps getting new users coming and asking for the same data.  However, the getSlowData() method hasn't completed yet.

So something like this:

```
@Cached
public getSlowData() {
...
}
```

Inside the interceptor, we check the cache and find that it's not cached, which passes us down to:

```
return getResultAndCache(methodInvocation, cacheKey);
```

I've never gotten comfortable with the whole concept of concurrency.  I think what I need is to mark that the getResultAndCache() method, for the given getSlowData(), has already been kicked off and subsequent requests should wait for the result.

Thanks for any thoughts or advice!

Comment: That is an interesting problem, blocking in progress calls for the same cache key seems logical to me. Maybe you could check the approach taken for similar spring projects: Spring Cache Abstraction, ehcache-spring-annotations and spring-modules-cache.

Comment: Inject your interceptor with a singleton `ConcurrentHashMap` of methods that have already started processing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did take a look at Spring's cache annotations on Friday. I'll take another look the other projects to see if I missed something. I think Spring is using some Spring-specific magic to deal this this issue, it wasn't obvious looking at their Interceptor, nor the one it extends.

Comment: @condit - That's a good idea. I was thinking something along those lines - a way to track which methods were started processing. I suppose I'll need to clean that up as well.  Sounds like something worth trying, thanks.

Comment: Implementing a cache is not a trivial task. Have you considered using the goolge guava cache? https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: @eiden - thanks for the comment. I'm not trying to implement a cache, just the annotation layer that calls the cache. I'm using Infinispan as the implementation.  The cache4guice library allows you to plugin multiple caches, just as the Spring Cache does.

Comment: I see. But maybe could still use the guava cache, as it implements the blocking-when-loading behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks again for the input @eiden I did look at Guava cache early on, however it's only an in-memory cache, and we had a specific use-case where we wanted to 'overflow' to an on-disk cache.  That's definitely been on my mind, not wanting to re-invent the wheel of a function already out there.  Moving from Guice to Spring is too extreme. And if I want to continue using AOP-based cache via annotations, then I'm fairly committed to using just one cache implementation. But your dead-on that the guava function is what I'm looking for.  I believe Guava cache passes a loader...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cache implementations synchronize calls to 'get' and 'set' but that's only half of the equation. What you really need to do is make sure that only one thread enters the 'check if loaded and load if not there' part. For most situations, the cost to serializing thread access may not be worth if there's

```
 1) no risk 
 2) little cost
```

to loading the data multiple times through parallel threads (comment here if you need more clarification on this). Since this annotation is used universally, I would suggest creating a second annotation, something like '@ThreadSafeCached' and the invoke method will look like this

```
    Object cacheElement = cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (cacheElement != null) {            
        LOG.debug("Returning element in cache: {}", cacheElement);            
    } else {
        synchronized(<something>) {
               // double-check locking, works in Java SE 5 and newer
           if ((cacheElement = cache.get(cacheKey)) == null) {
               // a second check to make sure a previous thread didn't load it
               cacheElement = getResultAndCache(methodInvocation, cacheKey);
           } else {
               LOG.debug("Returning element in cache: {}", cacheElement);            
           }
        }
    }
    return cacheElement;
```

Now, I left the part about what you synchronize on. It'd be most optimal to lock down on the item being cached since you won't make any threads not specifically loading this cache item wait. If that's not possible, another crude approach may be to lock down on the annotation class itself. This is obviously less efficient but if you have no control over the cache loading logic (seems like you do), it's an easy way out!

Comment: I forgot to say that in context of webapps, you also have the option of prefetching the information i.e. load it at startup so you won't get into race conditions at all. Much simpler than trying to battle with threads IMO :)

Comment: Thanks @HakunaM, that worked!  They key was what to synchronize on, and in this case I used the method class like:
`synchronized(methodInvocation.getClass())`